German EU blue card renewal
I was recently issued an EU blue card visa in my passport. The blue card expires when my passport (UK) expires in February 2025. My passport is almost due for renewal as it will be 10 years old in May 2024. Once I've renewed my passport, how do I renew my blue card? I assume the blue card validity is dependent on being associated with a valid passport and so renewing the passport will invalidate the old blue card visa. How long does it take to renew the blue card and can a temporary card be issued so I can leave Germany until the new card arrives? I live in Munich.

Does this answer your question? Can I renew my blue card (from Germany) even if my passport expired?
